# Echo a variable inside a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation

I'm trying to figure out how to echo a variable inside a variable.

This code below doesn't obviously work because I'm not echoing the variable

```
$tweet = get_field('tweet_msg'); //this is getting the string inputted by user in the custom field
$tweet_intent = '<div><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="'.$tweet.'">TEST</a> </div>';
```

but when ever I do PHP throws an error saying unexpected echo:

```
$tweet_intent = '<div style="margin-bottom:15px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="'.echo $tweet.'">TEST</a> </div>';
```

Full code:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );

function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
  $tweet = get_field('tweet_msg');
  $tweet_intent = '<div style="margin-bottom:15px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="'.$tweet.'">TEST</a> </div>';

  if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
    return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $tweet_intent, 2, $content );
  }

  return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
  $closing_p = '</p>';
  $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
  foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

    if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {        $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
    }
    if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
      $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
    }
  }     return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Comment: [*"This is not a duplicate."*](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35465691/1) - Oh, how so? It's pretty obvious here. You can't put an echo in like that. Place it befofre you've declared the variable.

Comment: you can't assign `echo` to a variable. simple remove it

Comment: You say “This code below doesn't obviously work” is the **correct code**. Maybe `$tweet` is empty or is not a string

Comment: @Fred-ii- I said that because i've checked out a number of other posts for this and some were being closed as duplicates when that wasnt even what the author was asking!

Comment: This guy/girl is probably just starting out and we should be nicer to him/her.

Comment: @fusion3k it does have a string in it. $tweet = get_field('tweet_msg'); passing the string to $tweet.

Comment: Here `echo $tweet_intent = '<div style="margin-bottom:15px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="'.$tweet.'">TEST</a> </div>';` - *problem solved*. It's valid syntax. or echo the function since you have a return for it.

Comment: Wow @Fred-ii- cranky much? Can you please remove what you did and add take a look at the code...it's not solved...

Comment: @thebestusernameeverThank you, it's not that I'm "just starting out" It's because this mod just jumped to conclusions. I included full code which clearly shows why I need to do what I'm doing.

Comment: @UriahsVictor Please pay attention: if the code by Fred doesn't work, then **your `$tweet` variable is empty.** No alternatives. Try to echo it before to see what is inside!

Comment: I did all that before I came here to post, the $tweet variable echos out exactly what was entered by user, I need to concat what was entered by user onto the tweet intent then do some work with that variable. I know trigger-finger-closing-topic mods like @Fred-ii- exist so I did my share of searching around before I decided to post!

Comment: just like @fusion3k said. Plus, we don't know if your code worked in the first place without the echo in there. You need to modify your question to tell us what works or not. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. You posted some code, didn't say anything other than the errors you got when placing that echo in there. I've given you 2 ways to do this, but you're giving me flack. Check for errors, update your question with what's not working then ping me back.

Comment: I have posted the full code, I thought you're a PHP guru, can't you see what's going on? I'm getting data entered by the user and i'm concating it into html which is then...nvm I've posted in the appropriate forum. It's clear that you don't see what I'm trying to achieve...of course I have error reporting on.

Comment: I've reopened your question. @UriahsVictor next time, do include more information and pertinent to what it is you want to do here. Like, we're supposed to guess. I mean c'mon. We weren't all born with code built into our DNA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem reside in your `<a href>` syntax.
Assuming that, after `get_field()`, the value of `$tweet` is 'Hello-World', your code:

```
$tweet_intent = '<div style="margin-bottom:15px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="'.$tweet.'">TEST</a> </div>';
```

put in `$tweet_intent` this string:

```
(...)<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="Hello-World">TEST</a> </div>
             └──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

As you can see, the quotation marks of `href` are closed **before** `$tweet` output.

You have to change your code in this way:

```
$tweet = get_field( 'tweet_msg' );
$tweet = rawurlencode( $tweet ); // only if encoding is not performed by get_field 
$tweet_intent = '
    <div style="margin-bottom:15px;">
         <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$tweet.'">TEST</a>
    </div>';
```